# return relational data list to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanted to return a list to my partial view from relational matching data of products. I have attached picture of edmx file where you will get idea about their relationship status! Problem is i just dont know how can i write this query or i need any iteration process to do it. Main goal is: I want to get all Products that the current user has bookmarked. Any question welcome. Thanks in advance

[image: Picture1]

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        [Authorize]
        public PartialViewResult _UserBookmark(string id)
        {
            using (mydb db = new mydb())
            {
                int userId = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == id).FirstOrDefault().UserId;//here i am getting user primary key id
                var ProductIds = db.Bookmarks.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();//here i am getting all Product primary keys under that user
                var ListOfProducts = db.Products.Where(x=>x.ProductId == "i dont know how to do it") // here i wanted to return matched all products 
                return PartialView("_UserBookmark",ListOfProducts);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `IEnmerable<Product> ListOfProducts  = db.Products.Where(x => ProductIds.Contains(x.ProductId))`, but you would need to use `IEnumerable<int> ProductIds = db.Bookmarks.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.ProductId);`

Comment: works! plz answer. is it the safe way to answer without risk of down vote?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and did not really state what you wanted to return (e.g. _I want to get all Products that the current user has bookmarked_). If you edit the question, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `.Contains` statement to return the Products where the `ProductId` is in your collection of `ProductIds`.

Change the method to

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[Authorize]
public PartialViewResult _UserBookmark(string id)
{
    using (mydb db = new mydb())
    {
        int userId = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == id).FirstOrDefault().UserId;
        // Get a collection of the ProductId's
        IEnumerable<int> ProductIds = db.Bookmarks
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.ProductId);
        IEnumerable<Product> ListOfProducts = db.Products
            .Where(x => ProductIds.Contains(x.ProductId))
        return PartialView("_UserBookmark", ListOfProducts);
    }
}
```

Note, if the results are for the current user, then consider just getting the current user in the method rather that passing their `Email` to the method. Note also that `.FirstOrDefault().UserId` would throw an exception is you passed an incorrect value to the method which resulted in `User` being `null`.